# Ensure proper bounds for custom control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I've created my own custom WPF control that just draws some text in its `OnRender` method, however, when I look at this control in the designer it does not take up any space. What do I need to do to make sure my control takes up the space as reported by the `FormattedText` object I have?

Comment: What does your control specifically do? I don't think overriding `OnRender()` is the best approach for almost any situation.

Comment: It just draws text, the purpose is just to draw text without leading overhang and at the baseline with regards to the line height.

Comment: I don't think I understood properly. What is the difference between your control and a regular `TextBlock`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of what I'm doing with the render method. I really don't need anything but the text, however, I was missing the calls to the `InvalidateMeasure` and `InvalidateArrange` after I've created the new geometry.

```
private Geometry textGeometry;

protected override void OnRender(System.Windows.Media.DrawingContext drawingContext)
{
    if (textGeometry == null)
    {
        var currentTypeface = new Typeface(FontFamily, FontStyle, FontWeight, FontStretch);

        var formattedText = new FormattedText(Text
            , System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
            , System.Windows.FlowDirection.LeftToRight
            , currentTypeface
            , FontSize
            , Foreground
            );

        var d = LineHeight - formattedText.Baseline;

        textGeometry = formattedText.BuildGeometry(new Point(-formattedText.OverhangLeading, d));
        textGeometry.Freeze();

        this.InvalidateMeasure();
        this.InvalidateArrange();
    }

    drawingContext.DrawGeometry(Foreground, null, textGeometry);
}
```